# How can I escape special characters?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline with a single web activity. In the header for the web activity I have a single header, which is `"Authorization":"v4cVQr3AkUwP3LMNUCSeQg==mirwVOd7MxPBGt6x0bEeIBTp4x8cCOkB+Vsa6cMfadskMllP5PcKjgZEExmVw4bvDpmKdki1+CaGPiSgrazLnR930R2BVmpZwq9y2K7Yj7REHpkmNNqCRn/XGpoKJkKByifQKyDTAr7StpZVUGEovw=="`

Basically, no matter what I try, I receive the following error:

> Error calling the endpoint 'https://rest.myabsorb.com'. Response
> status code: 'NA - Unknown'. More details: Exception message: 'NA -
> Unknown [ClientSideException] The format of value
> 'v4cVQr3AkUwP3LMNUCSeQg==mirwVOd7MxPBGt6x0bEeIBTp4x8cCOkB+Vsa6cMfadskMllP5PcKjgZEExmVw4bvDpmKdki1+CaGPiSgrazLnR930R2BVmpZwq9y2K7Yj7REHpkmNNqCRn/XGpoKJkKByifQKyDTAr7StpZVUGEovw=='
> is invalid. Request didn't reach the server from the client.

However, when I remove the special characters from the `Authorization` value, my request does get sent to the server (only, the server responds with a "incorrect password" message) - but the point is, if I manually remove these special characters, the request has a valid format according to ADF.

I have tried using a nested `@replace(replace(replace(<value>, '=', '\='), '+', '\+'), '/', '\/')` function to replace these special characters, but it does not work. I receive the same error.

Is the backslash `\` not the correct escape character to use? How can I get my web activity to make this request?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. I solved this by using `@concat('Bearer ', <token>)`. No `replace` function or any escape character needed.